# Why timer doesn't count?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this method:

```
    internal async Task PausingForPeriodOftimeAsync() {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Console.WriteLine( $"1. - async: Running for {sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds} ms");
        Console.WriteLine( $"1. - async: Time: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine($"2. - async: Running for {sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds} ms");
        Console.WriteLine($"2. - async: Time: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }
```

The result on screen:

> 1.- async: Running for 0 ms
>
> 1.- async: Time: 11:07:30
>
> 2.- async: Running for 7 ms
>
> 1.- async: Time: 11:07:35

I don't understand why the timer only ran for 5 milliseconds while DateTime shows (rightly) the time five seconds later. How is it possible?

Comment: `Milliseconds` vs `TotalMilliseconds`, see the linked question

Answer (score 1):

By using `sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds` you are getting the milliseconds part of the elapsed time. If you want to get the whole elapsed time consider using `sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds`.

Comment: or just `sw.ElapsedMilliseconds`